# Why does printing these values give different values in different OS and versions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, unicode

Why does printing these \x values give different values in different OS and versions?
Example:

```
print("A"*20+"\xef\xbe\xad\xde")
```

This gives different output in Python3 and 2 and in different platforms

In Microsoft's Windows:

Python2: `AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAï¾Þ`

Python3: `AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAï¾Þ`

In Kali:

Python2: `AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAﾭ`

Python3: `AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAï¾­Þ`

UPDATE: What I want is the exact Python2 output but with Python3? I tried many things(encoding, decoding, byte conversion) but realised \xde can't be decoded. Any other way to achieve what I want?

Comment: I think that is unicode, not hex that you are printing.

Comment: That's not hex.

Comment: So to be clear, you want to output `AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAﾭ`, silently ignoring the `\xde`?

Comment: Pls tell me why it was down voted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get consistent behavior on both Python 2 and Python 3, you'll need to be explicit about your intended output. If you want, `AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAﾭ`, then the `\xde` is garbage; if you want `AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAï¾Þ`, the `\xad` is garbage. Either way, the "solution" to printing what you've got is to explicitly use `bytes` literals and `decode` them with the desired encoding, ignoring errors. So to get `AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAﾭ` (interpreting as UTF-8), you'd do:

```
print((b"A"*20+b"\xef\xbe\xad\xde").decode('utf-8', errors='ignore'))
```

while to get `AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAï¾Þ` you'd do:

```
# cp1252 can be used instead of latin-1, depending on intent; they overlap in this case
print((b"A"*20+b"\xef\xbe\xad\xde").decode('latin-1', errors='ignore'))
```

Importantly, note the leading `b` on the literals; they're recognized and ignored on Python 2.7 (unless `from __future__ unicode_literals` is in effect, in which case they're needed just like in Python 3) and on Python 3, it makes the literals `bytes` literals (no special encoding assumed), rather than `str` literals, so you can decode in your desired encoding. Either way, you end up with raw bytes, which can then be decoded in the preferred encoding, with errors ignored.

Note that ignoring errors is usually going to be wrong; you're dropping data on the floor. 0xDEADBEEF isn't guaranteed to produce a useful byte string in any given encoding, and if that's not your real data, you're probably still risking errors by wanting to silently ignore undecodeable data.

If you want to write the raw bytes and let whatever is consuming `stdout` interpret them however it wants, you need to drop below the `print` level, since `print` on Python 3 is purely `str` based. To write the raw bytes on Python 3, you'd use `sys.stdout.buffer` (`sys.stdout` is text based, `sys.stdout.buffer` is the underlying buffered byte-oriented stream it wraps); you'd also need to manually add the newline (if desired):

```
sys.stdout.buffer.write(b"A"*20+b"\xef\xbe\xad\xde\n")
```

vs. on Python 2 where `stdout` isn't an encoding wrapper:

```
sys.stdout.write(b"A"*20+b"\xef\xbe\xad\xde\n")
```

For portable code, you can get a "raw stdout" ahead of time and use that:

```
# Put this at the top of your file so you don't have to constantly recheck/reacquire
# Gets sys.stdout.buffer if it exists, sys.stdout otherwise
bstdout = getattr(sys.stdout, 'buffer', sys.stdout)

# Works on both Py2 and Py3
bstdout.write(b"A"*20+b"\xef\xbe\xad\xde\n")
```

Comment: As you said it ignores \xde. Is there way to print raw bytes exactly like Py2 does?

Comment: @Anutrix: Not with `print`, but on Py3, `sys.stdout.buffer.write(b"A"*20+b"\xef\xbe\xad\xde\n"` would achieve the same effect. `sys.stdout.buffer` is the raw byte level file object for `stdout`.

Comment: Thx a lot. sys.stdout.buffer was what I was looking for. Maybe add that to your answer since I updated my question, so that I can accept your answer.

Comment: @Anutrix: Done. Made it a cross-version portable example too.

Answer (score 3):

It is a question of encoding.

In Latin1 or Windows 1252 encoding, you have:

```
0xef -> ï (LATIN SMALL LETTER I WITH DIAERESIS)
0xbe -> ¾ (VULGAR FRACTION THREE QUARTERS)
0xad -> undefined and non printed in your examples
0xde -> Þ (LATIN CAPITAL LETTER THORN)
```

In utf-8 encoding, you have:

`'\xef\xbe\xad'` -> `u'\uffad'` or `'ﾭ'` (HALFWIDTH HANGUL LETTER RIEUL-SIOS)
   `'\xde'` -> should raise an UnicodeDecodeError...

In Windows, Python2 or Python3 both use Windows 1252 code page (in your example). On Kali, Python2 sees the string as byte string and the terminal displays it in utf8, while Python3 assumes it already contains unicode character values and displays them directly.

As in Latin1 (and in Windows 1252 for all characters outside 0x80-0x9f) the byte code is the unicode value, that is enough to explain your outputs.

What to learn: be explicit whether strings contains unicode or bytes and beware of encodings!